# Program to check if list is in alternating form

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function in Python that checks if a given list of integers is strictly alternating i.e.alternately go up and down strictly

So for example:

```
alternating([]) = True

alternating([1,3,2,3,1,5]) = True

alternating([3,2,2,1,5])= False

alternating([3,2,1,3,5]) =  False
```

This is the code I could think of, but it isnt working for the empty list, does work for the rest and any changes I make gives me errors for all the rest.

```
def alternating(list):
  for i  in range(1,len(list)):
    if (((list[i]>list[i+1]) and (list[i]>list[i-1])) or ((list[i]  <list[i+1]) and (list[i]<list[i-1]))) :
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "strictly alternating"?

Comment: For starters, you can monkey patch the case of an empty list: `if not list: return True`. But you have a bug anyway.

Comment: It shouldnt work if the same number is repeated consecutively, like in the second example I provided

Comment: Then why is `3,2,1,3,5` false? That doesn't have the same number repeated consecutively.

Comment: @DeepSpace, that seems fine. But is there any better way that amounts to the same result?

Comment: He means that, comparing adjacent numbers, the relation should alternate between 'greater than' and 'less than.'

Comment: You have a bug anyway, `[1,3,2,3,2,1]` returns `True` because you are only looking at the first 3 indexes.

Comment: You probably want this function to return some value at the end (probably `True`). In addition, you can't possibly return `True` as a correct value by checking only an `O(1)` elements in the list (i.e., only `False` can be a correct value in that scenario).

Comment: yeah..I am a newbie..keep getting confused with the use of the return function.

Comment: Also, can the person who downvoted please tell me what I should do not to get one next time around?

Comment: `numpy.diff` seems useful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
def alternating(l):
    return all(cmp(a, b)*cmp(b, c) == -1 for a, b, c in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]))

assert alternating([]) is True
assert alternating([1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 5]) is True
assert alternating([3, 2, 2, 1, 5]) is False
assert alternating([3, 2, 1, 3, 5]) is False
assert alternating([1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1]) is False
```

Here are two simpler versions:

```
def alternating(l):
    for i in range(len(l)-2):
        if (l[i] < l[i+1]) and (l[i+1] > l[i+2]):
            continue
        if (l[i] > l[i+1]) and (l[i+1] < l[i+2]):
            continue
        return False
    return True
```

```
def alternating(l):
    for i in range(len(l)-2):
        if (l[i] < l[i+1]) and (l[i+1] < l[i+2]):
            return False
        if (l[i] > l[i+1]) and (l[i+1] > l[i+2]):
            return False
        if (l[i] == l[i+1]) or (l[i+1] == l[i+2]):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sure this is a very effective way, but I have not yet encountered any of the functions like all, zip ,cmp, etc in my course. So trying to do this in a very basic way.

Comment: Okay. Knowing that this was homework would have helped me. In future, please note in your question if you are asking about coursework.

Comment: Thanks...I was looking for that!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward way to do it:

```
def alternating(l):
  for i in range(1, len(l) - 1):
    if not (l[i - 1] < l[i] > l[i + 1] or
            l[i - 1] > l[i] < l[i + 1]):
      return False
  return True

print alternating([])
print alternating([1,3,2,3,1,5])
print alternating([3,2,2,1,5])
print alternating([3,2,1,3,5])
```

Comment: Excellent. I always forget that chained comparisons exist.

Answer (score 1):

Basic error #1:

```
for i  in range(1,len(list)):
    if (((list[i]>list[i+1]) and (list[i]>list[i-1])) or ...:
        return True
```

On the algorithmic perspective, you cannot possibly determine that a list of `n` elements is alternating by checking only `O(1)` elements.

---

Basic error #2:

Your function doesn't always return value. Although this is not mandatory in Python, in your specific case you probably want it to return a value, and even more so - a Boolean value.

Comment: What exactly should I modify in the code??Can you please suggest that?